# Android FragmentActivity with tabhost doesn't show the first tab's content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I'm a beginner android developer and I can't understand why my first tab content isn't shown. I have been searching on the Internet for quite a while, but I haven't succeeded yet. :(

Two other tabs are displayed properly, just the first one fails (despite the fragment I attach to it, so it's not the first fragment's problem, I think)

I tried to carefully follow some tutorials and studied many examples, but I still can't find the reason why...

Here is how I setup the tabHost:

```
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.main_tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("My").setIndicator(createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "My")), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("My", MyCinemasFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);  
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("All").setIndicator(createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "All")), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("All", AllCinemasFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Win!").setIndicator(createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Win!")), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Win!", OffersFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    this.onTabChanged("My");

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```

and this is my addTab method:

```
private static void addTab(TabsFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {

    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

However, I feel like onTabChanged messes everything up...

```
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement the createTabView()?

```
createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "My"))
```

In my experiences I lost all 3 of tab content because of the TabWidget fill up all the screen, even though set it "wrap_content". After changing it's height to "120dp" for testing, it showed up correctly.

How did you first tab content missing more precisely? Is it just show the background of parent element or? You can set a specific color to anyone of its parent elements to make sure what's displayed.